# https url not opening after configuring SSL for default website in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl

I configured the Default website in IIS for SSL by creating a CSR using the IIS itself, submitted it to a CA, and assigned the issued certificate as the server certificate. That's all is required in this world to setup server SSL. But when I open the https url it says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Which pillar should I bang my head against to get it working? The only help from microsoft I could find is that useless arcicle http://support.microsoft.com/?id=290391 that presupposes you are configuring a non-default website for SSL and goes on and on about port conflict. I'm using default website for https.

I'm using windows xp, IIS 5.1 and Microsoft Management Console 3.0.
Please help or courier me a shotgun for shooting myself.

Edit: After I configured IIS for SSL, the Apache Tomcat server which had been configured on port 8080 has suddenly stopped working. The 8080 urls just timeout. What is the connection?

Edit: Because I can't live without Tomcat on my machine, I used another machine to setup IIS SSL after stopping the tomcat there. I face the same problem there, "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Please help before I shoot myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't shoot!

XP has given me fits with SSL...  have you tried setting the application pool to high/isolated setting up the website with an identity under COM?

That seemed to solve some issues for me.

Also - did you make sure to set it up in the correct stores?  Is this an application that is running under your account or a service account?  If it is a service account you may need to do a RUN AS on the certificate management console and add under that user's personal store as well as under the appropriate store for the machine/computer.

Good luck.